# Android- Saving File (Input & Output Stream) throws Exception (open failed: EINVAL (Invalid argument)) in Pre-lollipop devices

Tags: android, file, file-io, filestream, fileinputstream

**Android- Saving File (Input & Output Stream) throws Exception (open failed: EINVAL (Invalid argument)) in Pre-lollipop devices**

I am downloading a file from URL (`www.xyz.in/file/9`) and saving in SD CARD.

Folder created code:

```
try {
    //String folder_name = "NewFolder";
    File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Venky");
    if (!f.exists()) {
        f.mkdirs();
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.v("MTV", " createFileDirectory exception" + e);
}
```

Below I posted a (Download and Saving file) code,
**In android lollipop, It works fine** to download and saved the file in SD Card.

**it doesn't works on Pre-lolipop devices. It throws Exception.**

```
protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {
            int count;
            try {
                URL url = new URL(f_url[0]);
                URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
                conection.connect();
                // this will be useful so that you can show a tipical 0-100% progress bar
                int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();

                    String depo = conection.getHeaderField("Content-Disposition");
                    String depoSplit[] = depo.split("filename=");
                    filename = depoSplit[1].replace("filename=", "").replace("\"", "").trim();

                filename=filename.trim();
                String Filetype = conection.getContentType();
                Log.v("fileName", " " + filename + " FileLength " + lenghtOfFile + " Filetype " + Filetype);

                InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 8192);

                OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Venky/" + filename);
                Log.v("", "" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + R.string.app_name + "/" + filename);
                byte data[] = new byte[1024];
                long total = 0;
                while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                    total += count;
                    // publishing the progress....
                    // After this onProgressUpdate will be called
                    publishProgress("" + (int) ((total * 100) / lenghtOfFile));
                    // writing data to file
                    output.write(data, 0, count);
                }
                // flushing output
                output.flush();
                // closing streams
                output.close();
                input.close();
                DownloadSucess = true;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                DownloadSucess = false;
                Log.e("Error: ","Download Exception "+ e);
            }

            return null;
        }
```

Logcat (Exception):

```
>E/Error:: Download Exception java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/sdcard0/Venky/FileName : smile-please.png: open failed: EINVAL (Invalid argument)
```

Note: In manifest, Both `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` & `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permissions are used.

Comment: You are not checking the return value of mkdirs().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value of your variable `filename` is `FileName : smile-please.png` and not -what you think- `smile-please.png`.

Just log the contents of filename before use.

Comment: Yes, I used the Logcat.  file name is smile-please.png

Comment: my Logcat --   V/TMR: file /storage/sdcard0/Venky/FileName : smile-please.png

Comment: Indeed. That's what i said. Don't you see that the filename is NOT `smile-please.png` but `FileName :smile-please.png`. You have a `EINVAL (Invalid argument)` because of the `: ` in the file name.

Comment: I didnt use Colon ( : ) . Can you tell clear where i am use. I will change

Comment: Cant understand. Please edit your answer and post correct code.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should first try to create that directory, the file and then check whether them exists or not.

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Venky/";

File dir = new File(path);

boolean created = dir.mkdir();

if (created) {
    File fp = new File(path + filename);}
```